# При перезапуске приложения из значка на рабочем столе запускается новый mainActivity

Tags: android, activity

Данные, введенные пользователем иногда пропадают с экрана, когда пользователь разворачивает приложение из свернутого состояния. С помощью toast отладки замечено что когда сворачиваешь приложение вызывается onPause, далее вместо того чтобы развернуть приложение пользователь щелкает на значок на рабочем столе телефона и в хорошем варианте запускается onRestart, а в плохом onCreate. Вот картинка которая пояснит что происходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот. Когда выполняется onCreate то запускается как бы еще одно Activity, с пустыми полями, которые заполнял пользователь. При этом savedInstanceState==null, но может быть потому что я его не создавал. Как не допустить появления новых Activity при перезапуске?

Вот мой onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    showToast("onCreate");
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        showToast("savedInstanceState != null");
    }
    if (savedInstanceState == null){

        showToast("savedInstanceState == null");
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //не дает экрану выключаться
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    // Делает настройки ActionBar'а
    initActionBar();}
```

Если нажать назад, то лишнее Activity закрывается и данные снова на экране.

update вот мой манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.slaker1990.myapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
    <!--configChanges не позволяет Activity перезагружатся при перевороте экрана-->
    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема, в том, что заполняемые пользователем поля обнуляются при перезапуске/перезагрузке приложения?

Comment: То есть иногда открывается старое активити с заполненными данными, а иногда поверх старого ещё одно с пустыми полями? Какие-то флаги для активити добавляли в манифесте?

Comment: Манифест еще покажите.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Добавил манифест

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Начал анализировать интенты от которых запускается активити. Интент первого запуска отличается от интента при перезапуске с созданием нового активити наличием `bnds=[[63,1272][255,1464](has extras)]`. 
 Поиск вывел меня на английский stackowerflow и статью на девелопере [Таски и стек переходов назад](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)
. Вообщем решение получилось добавлением в манифест `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` в раздел activity, что не дает приложению создавать новые активити